# В изоморфном приложении (javascript) обязательно ли должны совпадать данные?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Если сравнить код на клиенте и на сервере из этого примера [github set-cookie app](https://github.com/spikebrehm/set-cookie), видно, что предаваемые данные одиннаковые:

Клиент

```
var setCookie = require('set-cookie');

setCookie('myCookie', 'the value of the cookie', {
    domain: '.example.org'
});
```

Сервер

```
var setCookie = require('set-cookie');

// In, for example, an Express middleware.
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    setCookie('myCookie', 'the value of the cookie', {
        domain: '.example.org',
        res: res
    });
    next();
});
```

Из этого вытекает несколько вопросов:

1. Обязательно ли должны совпадать данные на клиенте на сервере? 
   Если да, то как контролировать, чтобы данные всегда совпадали.
2. Насколько хорошо такое дублирование?

Comment: мне кажется вы не правильно поняли о чем говорилось в справке. Это не пример клента и сервера **одного** приложения, это пример как использовать этот модуль на клиенте, и второй пример как использовать этот модуль в nodejs

Comment: Похоже, что Вы правы.